# ngDialog in ES6 Angular 1.5 controller

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, ng-dialog

I'm trying to rewrite my Angular 1.5 code to ES6. I'm using `ng-dialog` and I'm importing it but not injecting it into the controller as I'm trying to make it a dependency of the module itself. I have the following code:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import ngDialog from '../libraries/ng-dialog';

const template = `<div>
        <button ng-click="ctrl.openTheDialog()">Click Me</button>
    </div>`;

class MyController {
    constructor($scope) {
        'ngInject';
        this.$scope = $scope;
    }

    openTheDialog() {
        ngDialog.open({
            template: templateUrl,
            scope: this.$scope
        });
    }
}

angular.module('myApp', ['ngDialog'])
    .component('myComponent', {
        template: template,
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        controller: MyController
    });
```

When I click the button, I get an error message that `open` is not a function. I'm not really sure where I made the mistake here. Can someone help point out the error? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you have to really inject 'ngDialog', instead of importing it, because it has to be registered in your application. Don't forget to register it via 'angular.module(....)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you just need to set the ngDialog to a property in the constructor:

```
constructor($scope, ngDialog) {
    this.ngDialog = ngDialog;
    ...
    ...
}

openTheDialog() {
    this.ngDialog.open({
    ...
    });
}
```